# java jdbc insert fire a trigger in oracle db

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

suppose that

- i make an insert into a table using Java Jdbc
- the insert fire a trigger

java waits that the trigger finish the execution or it continue the execution??

(using oracle 11g)

if it dose continue without wait, there i way to wait the end of the trigger execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INSERT` statement is not complete until all the triggers that need to fire have fired and run to completion.  It doesn't matter what front-end language you use to issue the `INSERT` statement, the `INSERT` must always wait for the triggers to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Even If a `INSERT` calls `N NUMBER OF TRIGGER`, First all the `TRIGGERS` will complete execution while the `INSERT` will wait, and then it will come back to `INSERT`

that is logical as well, if I am firing some triggers before inserting into a database than I would want them to complete before inserting.

The JAVA wont move to next statement until the INSERT statement responds and it wont respond until it has completed execution and it will not complete execution until All Triggers that are Triggered are completed.