# Java Spring move on execution after database trigger

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Currently using  Spring JPA repository to save the data , but there is a table trigger after insert the record into the table, and i found that the spring JPA just move on after calling the repository save method without waiting for the trigger finish its job? Is there a way the spring JPA repository can wait till the Oracle table trigger finishes before completing? Thanks

Comment: By definition a trigger happens after the DML operation completes. The JPA operation does not know anything about the trigger in the DB

Comment: "a trigger happens after the DML operation completes" That depends on the trigger. So the solution might be to change the type of trigger, but if that is possible depends on the work done by the trigger.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012960/java-jdbc-insert-fire-a-trigger-in-oracle-db?rq=1 even suggests the opposite.

Comment: I think we need more information about what work is done in the trigger and how you come to the conclusion, that JPA does does not wait for the trigger to finish.